# Why can an array can be initialized with a variable as length in java?

Tags: java, c++, arrays

I try use a integer array in java with the code below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = testArray(100);
        System.out.println(array.length);
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
           System.out.println(array[i]);
    }

    public static int[] testArray(int size){
        int[] array = new int[size];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
           array[i] = i;
        return array;
    }
```

I also test an integer array in C++ as below:

```
       #include<iostream>
       using namespace std;

       void getArray(int size)
       {
            int array[size];
            for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
                array[i]=i; 
      }

      int main()
      {
           getArray(10);
           return 0;
      }
```

And I always get the right answer with the two snippets, why? since I think that the length of an array cannot be variable for language such as java, c and c++.

Comment: What error are you expecting? Why do you thing that this code should not work correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The three languages are different, and the features of the different languages will, well, differ. In particular, in C99 you can define arrays of a variable in the stack (for those that program mainly Java, this is commonly used to refer to a size that is not a compile time constant, not that the array will change sizes).

In C++ you cannot declare them in the stack (GCC allows this, with a non-conforming extension to the language that mimics C99 behavior), but you can dynamically allocate memory with `new` of the given size and store the pointer in a variable.

In Java you cannot create an array in the stack ever, and all you can do is dynamically allocate the array with `new` and store a reference.

```
int size = 100;

// C99
int data[size];

// C++
// int data[size];          // error, but allowed by gcc
int *data = new int[size]; 

// Java
int[] data = new int[size];
```

Comment: @NicolBolas: Right I was thinking right, typing wrong. I meant if the array size was held in a variable, as in the question. Thanks for picking it up.

Answer (score 2):

Java and C are different languages. What's allowed in standard C only as dynamic allocations (`malloc`/`calloc`) is allowed in Java by default, because all array allocations in Java are *dynamic* anyway; the concept of explicit stack allocation is missing from Java.

Comment: I just try the code with c++ and get no error, why? My c++ code is added above. @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @jerry_sjtu: Are you compiling with GCC? It has an extension that allows for C99 style of variable length arrays that are not C++ standard conformant.

Comment: Yes, I compile it with g++. So the array with a variable as length is dynamic allocated when compiled with g++ while an array with a fixed length is static allocated?

Comment: @jerry_sjtu Many compilers, including `gcc`, have extensions that allow arrays of variable length. It is allocated on the stack, so unlike the Java version, you cannot return that array from your function.

Answer (score 2):

Length of an array in Java is not variable. It is defined upon creation of the array (that is, *dynamically at runtime*), but cannot be changed after that.

Moreover, every array has a `length` property that can be used to make a for loop able to iterate through an array of any length:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
   System.out.println(array[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing variable here. You are initializing the array by passing the size to a method that creates an array of the requested size. In other words, you cannot manipulate the size of the array after initialization, unlike with `ArrayList` where you can vary the size.

Comment: @isbadawi The question is badly worded then. "variable length" seems to imply that the length of the array can vary, which is not the case.

Comment: @torrentialcoding: I assume that you come from a Java background. The term *variable length array* (VLA) is how the C standard refers to that construct, where as isbadawi points out the size of the array is *read* from a variable.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Thanks for the clarification. The way the question was worded, it sounded like a non-question. My answer looks like a non-answer now :|